# How could I test a port forward attempt was successful

Tags: linux, port

I have set a random port number to a private IP address that's connected to my network.
This device that exists at that private ip on the network is running linux.

I setup this port foward from a different machine - the actual device connected at the end of the private ip I specified in the port forward doesnt have much software, its a fresh OS install.

For the sake of this question, I am curious if its possible to somehow connect to this device or even ping it thought the global dynamic ip and port number, without actually installing a webserver/other software on the device to test the ip and port is being redirected to that private ip(device)

Comment: I have "telnet lite" (a free iPhone app), just for the sole purpose of testing port forwards.  Turn wifi off on the phone and connect using cellular.   Specify the port number to use when connecting in telnet lite.  Depending on what the port does the display on the app may or may not make much sense, but you can find out if you are reaching the machine from the outside or not.

Comment: Note that firewalls/NAT do not OPEN ports, they just either allow or block them. Only server applications (like webservers) actually open the ports. If you allow a port through your NAT, and forward it to an IP, the port will still be closed unless there is a service on that IP at that port. So if you are asking whether you can test the port forwarding without installing and running a service on the target port, then you won't be able to determine that the NAT rule works (except maybe logging firewall hits on the target port).

Comment: @FrankThomas That was my intention - to test without installing a service. But if what you are saying is true, it seems weird that a Router has a dependency which allows the forward only if a service is setup on the private ip specified - How would it know this? Ontop of knowing, I assume each service has different APIs, exmaple a Steam game server, a web server etc.

Comment: the router does not have a dependency; the port forwarding will work if configured correctly, but it forwards to a closed port. an external client can't tell if the packet was bounced by the NAT wall or the target host, so you can't test it because you can't easilly tell a successful test from a failure. If you glued the hinges of a door to a solid wall, you could open the door, but there is no hole behind the door that you could go through.

Comment: so in essence in your scenario, someone connects to the external gateway on the port, and NAT forwards that connection in to the target host, but when it gets there, it hits a brick wall. Testing utilities (like telnet, nmap, and canyouseeme.org) attempt to connect to the service behind the NAT wall, and if they can't, they report a failure. the testing utility can't tell why it failed, or where it failed, only that it did. in order to get a successful result, the utility must be able to connect to the service on the port.

Comment: @FrankThomas With regards to those testing utilities you mentioned, If I ran 2 tests, 1 with a port forward setup(no service attached), and one with no port forward setup, both tests would return an exact identical failure message - on all test utilities. Correct?

Comment: every one I've ever seen, yes, and the theory behind it says so as well. Those tools are designed to test service reachability. The network between the two end points is transparent to either end of the connection. IP networks are designed that way, because they are packet switched, and every packet in a connection may take a different route. The only way you can tell that a packet went all the way to its destination is if the service on the other end responds. otherwise it times out, and you can't tell whether the packets were received at all, unless some entity on the path sends a response.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is if you configured the internal device to log firewall hits on the port. then you could attempt to connect from outside, which will fail, but if the firewall log shows that the hit was blocked on the internal device itself, then the forward rule worked and the connection packets were correctly forwarded.

Comment: @FrankThomas I see, with regards to *some entity on the path* - that would usually be a service needed which we are speaking about right? A router wouldn't have anything on the path *after* its port info stuff. Sorry for the excessive clarification, as you mentioned some new terminology I just want to make sure whether its a new concept entirely.

Comment: network entities like firewalls CAN be configured to send messages back to the source indicating that a packet has been dropped or that a port is closed. most of the time they don't however, because that can allow someone to confirm that the host exists and is firewalled.

Answer (score 0):

If [netcat](/questions/tagged/netcat) is installet on the client :

```
nc -zw3 <IP> <PORT> && echo "Socket UP & running" || echo >&2 "Socket unreachable"
```